# Is there generic way to mirror a pair (pair<A,B> to pair<B,A>)?

Tags: c++, std-pair

for example, to mirror a `pair < int , float >` to `pair < float , int >`, I can create a template function like this:

```
template<class AB,class BA>
void mirror(const AB& ab,BA& ba){
    ba.first=ab.second;
    ba.second=ab.first;
}

int main(){
    pair<int,float> ab;
    ab.first=3;
    ab.second=2.0;
    pair<float,int> ba;
    mirror<decltype(ab),decltype(ba)>(ab,ba);
    printf("%d\n",ba.second);
    return 0;
}
```

but this method cannot handle a pair in another pair, e.g.:

`pair < bool , pair< int , float > >` to `pair < pair < float , int > , bool >`:

```
pair<bool,pair<int,float> > a_bc;
pair<pair<float,int>,bool> cb_a;
mirror<decltype(a_bc),decltype(cb_a)>(a_bc,cb_a);
```

`pair < pair < A , B >, pair < C , D > >` to `pair < pair < D , C > , pair< B , A > >`:

```
pair<pair<A,B>,pair<C,D> > ab_cd;
pair<pair<D,C>,pair<B,A> > dc_ba;
mirror<decltype(ab_cd),decltype(dc_ba)>(ab_cd,dc_ba)
```

is it possible to write mirror template functions (e.g.:2 mirror function templates, one for pair, another for non-pair, then use recursion) functions which can handle all cases above?

Comment: this mehtod can;t handle anything that T1 != T2 where T1,T2 are the types of the pair

Comment: Probably you can detect if one template parameter is pair (it has first_type and second_type typedefs), and then you can make a recursive call. But this doesn't actually garantuee that the parameter is pair... i am not sure if it can be solved in a nice and safe way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may create 2 overloads:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr const T& mirror(const T& t)
{
    return t;
}

template<class A, class B>
constexpr auto mirror(const std::pair<A, B>& p)
{
    return std::make_pair(mirror(p.second), mirror(p.first));
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/jdfkbO)

Comment: Elegant. Could you (or would you need to) use `decltype(auto)` for the first `mirror` to avoid copies?

Comment: @melak47: return type changed.

Comment: What is the point of the first mirror function? Why doesn't it work without it?

Comment: @Rozina: It is to handle non pair elements as `char` or `float` and so stops the *recursion* of the pair version.

Comment: Thanks to your demo I just came to the same conclusion by trying it out :)

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename S1, typename S2> std::pair<std::pair<S2, S1>, std::pair<T2, T1>> 
    mirror(const std::pair<std::pair<T1, T2>, std::pair<S1, S2>>& p)
{
    return std::pair<std::pair<S2, S1>, std::pair<T2, T1>>(mirror(p.second), 
                                                           mirror(p.first));
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename S> std::pair<S, std::pair<T2, T1>>
    mirror(const std::pair<std::pair<T1, T2>, S>& p)
{
    return std::pair<S, std::pair<T2, T1>>(p.second, mirror(p.first));
}

template<typename T, typename S1, typename S2> std::pair<std::pair<S2, S1>, T> 
    mirror(const std::pair<T, std::pair<S1, S2>>& p)
{
    return std::pair<std::pair<S2, S1>, T>(mirror(p.second), p.first);
}

template<typename T, typename S> std::pair<S, T> 
    mirror(const std::pair<T, S>& p)
{
    return std::pair<S, T>(p.second, p.first);
}


 int main() {
    pair<bool, pair<int, float> > a_bc;
    pair<pair<float, int>, bool> cb_a = mirror(a_bc);

    pair<pair<int, double>, pair<bool, pair<char, float>>> ab__c_de;
    pair<pair<pair<char, float>, bool>, pair<double, int>> de_c__ab = mirror(ab__c_de);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can in the `pair` class implement e.g.

```
pair<B, A> swap() {
    pair<B, A> tmp;
    tmp->first = this->second;
    tmp->second = this->first;
    return tmp;
}
```

and just call it when need.

Comment: It's not obvious in the code, but it's tagged [tag:std-pair], so we should assume that there's a hidden `using std::pair` somewhere in the source.  So it would need to be a non-member function.

Answer (score 0):

Try function template overloading to support the nest mirror for pair:

```
template<class AB,class BA>
void mirror(const AB& ab,BA& ba){
    ba = ab;
}
template<class A,class B,class C,class D>
void mirror(const pair<A, B>& a, pair<C, D>& b){
    mirror(a.first, b.second);
    mirror(a.second, b.first);
}
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/XPuS6l)